# Add class after x second and remove class on scroll

Tags: jquery

I would like a class be added to .readmoreArrow after 2 seconds (after pageload) and then once the user scrolls the class is to be removed.

I have written the following jQuery:

```
$('.readmoreArrow').delay(2000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).addClass('show');
        }, 2000);
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.readmoreArrow').removeClass('show');
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="homepagearrow">
    <a href="#component" class="readmoreArrow">scroll for more<span></span></a>
</div>
```

but it doesn't appear to be working. The class doesn't get added to .readmoreArrow

The following error is displayed in the Console:

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
$('.readmoreArrow').delay(2000, function() {
```

any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: which part isnt working, whats happening to the DOM? class getting added? any errors in the console?

Comment: Can we see the HTML too?

Answer (score 2):

Try using just `setTimeout`:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('.readmoreArrow').addClass('show');
    }, 2000)
})
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.readmoreArrow').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
body {
  height:2000px;
}
.readmoreArrow {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
.show {
  background: orange;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="readmoreArrow"></div>
```

Comment: That appears to be giving me an error: TypeError: $(...) is null

$('.readmoreArrow').addClass('show');

Comment: @RustyIngles wich errors? please make a fiddle with your code

Comment: @RustyIngles don't put those functions inside the document readytry that

Comment: It's almost impossible to help u just with the live site....if you can try to replicate an example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I edited the script to the following, which worked:

```
setTimeout( "jQuery('#readmoreArrow').addClass('show');",3000 );

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      jQuery('#readmoreArrow').addClass("hide");  
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use queue method (https://api.jquery.com/queue/) to queue your function calls in combination with delay.

```
$('.readmoreArrow').delay(2000)
                   .queue(function(next){
                     $(this).addClass('show');
                   })

$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('.readmoreArrow').removeClass('show');
});
```